# Docker - Container accessing outside database

Tags: docker

I have a docker container which is a tomcat server. I need to connect to a PostgreSQL database which is not on a docker container. I cannot figure how to set my container to access an host outside of the NAT network.

I need my tomcat server to connect on the PostgreSQL database.

I'm on Windows 10. My Tomcat container is on CentOS 7.

Thanks a lot!

Yann

Comment: How are you configuring your Docker network? Bridge? Host? Something else?

Comment: I tried with bridge and with host. I also tried to add dns. I surely doing something wrong but I can't figure out.

Comment: Are you using the maintained Tomcat image from Docker hub? If so, link it, if not, provide the Dockerfile you wrote please. Also, what is the error you are receiving specifically?

Comment: I finally figured out how to do the connection but are some strange things I can't explain ;) The container cannot ping my database server (either with the domain name or the IP). I also cannot ping www.google.com. But if I do a curl to google.com it works. So I tried to telnet my database and with the ip it works. I modify my application configuration to use the IP address and the connection to the database server works. I've tried to specify my DNS server with the --dns=MY_DNS_IP but it don't resolve domain name.